# How to get a table inside a div, searching div by a certain id using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html-table, html-agility-pack

There is a html like

```
   <div id="info_tab_members">
        <div id="info_members" class="tabslevel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#info_tab_members_past">Past members</a></li>
                <li><a href="#info_tab_members_live">Live musicians</a></li> 
            </ul>

            <div id="info_tab_members_all">
                <div class="ui-tabs-panel">
                <!-- THIS TABLE I WANT -->
                <table class="display tblClass" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">....
                  <!-- DATA I WANT -->
                </table>
               </div>
            </div>                              

            <div id="info_tab_members_current">
                <div class="ui-tabs-panel">
                    <table class="display tblClass" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">        ...
                     </table>
                 </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
```

How to get the table  that is within div with id `info_tab_members_all`?
something to consider is that there are several tables that have a common class `display tblClass`

I have tried:

first I tried to do

```
foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("table[@class='display tblClass']/tbody/tr"))
{
...
}
```

but the issue is that I get data from all tables that have `display tblClass`
  so then I tried:

```
 var tbl = doc.DocumentNode.
                SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='info_tab_members_all']").
                SelectNodes("table[@class='display tblClass']/tbody/tr").
                ToList();
```

but I get error:

> “Object reference not set to an instance of an object”

How can I specify the table i want with the div id:  `'info_tab_members_all'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to use [`HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors/), then you're in luck,

```
var table = htmlDoc.QuerySelectorAll("#info_tab_members_all table");
// table is `IList<HtmlNode>`
```

If not, then you just need the right XPath. Here's a [great reference for converting CSS to XPath](https://johnresig.com/blog/xpath-css-selectors/) and vice versa.

```
var table = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='info_tab_members_all']/*/table")
// table is `HtmlNode`
```